# Ubuntu inner Docker Containers

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I pulled an Ubuntu image from docker-hub and I want to open it with an interface in the Docker Container. How I can do this?

I'm trying to execute `docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash` but this opens an Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: You need a graphics card for Ubuntu, which docker is not intended for.  Look into VirtualBox instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is clearly not a use case for Docker. However, this is possible and can be achieved using a VNC server.

Run the following command:

```
docker run -p 5901:5901 queeno/ubuntu-desktop
```

Then connect to your Ubuntu container via a VNC client at `localhost:5901`. The default login password for that image is `password`. It will look like this:

[image]

Ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/queeno/ubuntu-desktop/